# How to close the Paypal Checkout window if no ckeckout is done

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'm using Paypal In Context Checkout on a tablet-device.
As defined by Paypal,  on all mobile or tablet-devices a full-size window page popping up after the on-click Event from within the Homepage, or the page hosting the checkout-button.
I want this page automatically return to the page hosting the on-click Event button, if there will be no actual Checkout within let's say 5 Minutes.
Because I don't want the page to Show up for ever, if somebody touches the Paypal checkout button on the Homepage just of being curious.

Is there a possibility to modify the JavaScript accordingly?